# Program is checking next available row in the wrong sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I've written a code that would copy data from a bunch of Excel workbooks (paths are read from a dedicated txt file) to a master sheet. The issue I'm having right now is that instead of checking for and pasting in the next available row in the MASTER workbook, the code is checking for the next available row in the source workbooks and pasting in the corresponding row number in the master workbook.

Here's what I have atm. Please have a look

---

```
Open PathFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, SourceFile

    Set Source = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile)

    With Source.Sheets("Action Tracker")
        lastRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 10 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("F" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            CopyRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet").Rows(Range("F100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
        End If

    End With

    Source.Close SaveChanges:=False
    CB.Clear
    Set CopyRange = Nothing

Loop
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste that in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is inside the following line:

```
CopyRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet").Rows(Range("F100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
```

Range, when used alone (not something.Range), is a shortcut to ActiveSheet.Range

You can try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")
    CopyRange.Copy .Rows(.Range("F100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Vince but it's still doing the same thing :s

Comment: Your comment regarding the ActiveSheet.Range inspired the solution I found. I just added. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet").Activate

CopyRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet").Rows(Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)